# Clicking on specific marker but it does not return the right coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to click on the specific marker that are displayed on the map to return me the coordinates. I am not sure why it always return me the same coordinates even though i have clicked on another marker which is far apart.

```
  ArrayList<Coordinates> coordinates=(ArrayList<Coordinates>)bundle.getSerializable("key");
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {

            double lati=coordinates.get(i).getLat();
            double longLat=coordinates.get(i).getLongt();
            marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                    position(
                            new LatLng(lati, longLat)));
        }

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                LatLng current_position = marker.getPosition();
                Double lat = current_position.latitude;
                Double longt = current_position.longitude;
                System.out.println(lat);
                System.out.println(longt);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this block of code:

```
 LatLng current_position = marker.getPosition();
```

With this:

```
 LatLng current_position = arg0.getPosition();
```

Hope that Helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
    LatLng current_position = marker.getPosition();
    Double lat = current_position.latitude;
    Double longt = current_position.longitude;
    System.out.println(lat);
    System.out.println(longt);
    return true;
}
```

Here you are referencing `marker`; switch to `arg0` instead:

```
LatLng currentPos = arg0.getPosition();
```